# What do these pronouns refer to?

Tags: meaning, pronouns

> Who blames me?  Many, no doubt; and I shall be called discontented.  I could not help it; the restlessness was in my nature; it agitated me to pain sometimes.  Then my sole relief was to walk along the corridor of the third story, backwards and forwards, safe in the silence and solitude of the spot, and allow my mind’s eye to dwell on whatever bright visions rose before it—and, certainly, they were many and glowing; to let **my heart** be heaved by the exultant **movement**, **which**, while (1) **it** swelled (2) **it** in trouble, expanded (3) **it** with life; and, best of all, to open my inward ear to a tale that was never ended—a tale my imagination created, and narrated continuously; quickened with all of incident, life, fire, feeling, that I desired and had not in my actual existence. (*Jane Eyre*, Charlotte Brontë)

Are “movement”, “which”, and “(1) it” co-referent (*ie* the same things)?  Are “my heart”, “(2) it”, and “(3) it” co-referent?

Comment: Right, they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are exactly correct.  The first "it" refers to the "exultant movement."  The second and third refer to "my heart."